# Increasing line spacing, but not for figure captions

Tags: captions, typography, line-spacing

I have used `\linespread` to get 1.5 spacing for my document, but is there a way to do this so it doesn't increase the spacing of my figure captions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Did you try with the `setspace` pckage and the switch `\onehalfspacing`? Normally, it takes care of this sort of things